# How do I set a default line size in plotnine?

Tags: python, plot, plotnine

I've been using plotnine to plot in Python and I would like to set up a default line size for all plots. Unfortunately, changing `line` inside my custom theme only affects background elements.

In R using `ggplot` [it is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418209/how-to-set-a-default-line-size-in-a-ggplot2-theme-ggtheme) to run `update_geom_defaults("line", list(size = desired size))` to get the desired behaviour. Is there such an alternative for plotnine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found the solution to this. As indicated by the [Plotnine API](https://plotnine.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/plotnine.geoms.geom.geom.html#plotnine.geoms.geom.geom) all geoms have an attribute called `DEFAULT_AES` containing the default values used for plotting. New default values can be set by changing the values of this dictionary. For instance, to set a new line size one can run:

```
import plotnine as p9
p9.geoms.geom_line.DEFAULT_AES['size']=desired_size
```