# How to set default size for `geom_line` in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the default thickness of `geom_line` using the size aesthetic. This question has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53418209/how-to-set-a-default-line-size-in-a-ggplot2-theme-ggtheme) but the solution - to set the default value using `update_geom_defaults` does not work for me.

Here's a minimum reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

update_geom_defaults("line", list(size = 2))

data(ChickWeight)

ChickWeight %>%
  filter(Chick %in% c("1", "2", "3")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = weight, colour = Chick)) +
  geom_line()
```

The result I get is:

[image: Line plot - size is still 1]

`update_geom_defaults` does work for changing e.g. the default colour. Any idea what's going on here and how to successfully change the default size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `linewidth` to change the thickness like this:

```r
library(tidyverse)

update_geom_defaults("line", list(linewidth = 2))

data(ChickWeight)

ChickWeight %>%
  filter(Chick %in% c("1", "2", "3")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Time, y = weight, colour = Chick)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-02-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Ahh thanks - so they've deprecated `size` - I can't keep up